# Why can't I use delete() inside a loop?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I'm having some troubles with delete operator inside a do-while loop, something like this:

```
double* n1=new double(0);

do{

cin >> *n1;

~stuff

delete n1;

}while...
```

How do I fix this? also is initializing the double to zero in the beginning correct?

Comment: You've allocated `n1` only once (outside the loop), deleted in the last of the do-while iteration. What would happen in the next iteration?

Comment: What is the reason you want to allocate a single `double` value dynamically to begin with? What is the *actual* problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: I've thought about that but my teacher gave as an assignment which states to avoid memory allocation inside the loop, I thought there might've been another method.

Comment: The key word there is "avoid memory allocation". There's nothing in the shown code that requires memory allocation.

Comment: Is it possible you have been programming in Java or C# before, where one typically have to use `new` to create new objects or values? You don't have to do that in C++, just define it as `double n1 = 0;` and use `n1` as usual.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm creating a calculator, I just gave an example with a single double value, there are a few actually. I'm confused with the fact that I can't get to cin new double values after deleting the memory.

Comment: That's because after `delete n1` the pointer `n1` is invalid, it doesn't point anywhere you can use anymore. Any attempt to dereference that pointer (as in `*n1`) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay I see now. but can't cin>>*n1 fix that since I'll be entering new values. I'm just a beginner btw, only used c++ so far.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I fix this?

Don't use `new`.

```
do {
    double n;
    std::cin >> n;

    /* stuff */        
} while (/*...*/)
```

> is initializing the double to zero in the beginning correct?

It isn't invalid. It's arguably unnecessary.

Comment: furthermore, in C++ you shouldn't use `new` unless you are absolutely certain that you need to. Instead, [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) should be used.

Comment: I have to tho, it's a requirement in my assignment.

Comment: @Keti_Kh If this is about an assignment, you should understand the [difference between stack- and heap-allocated memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/), as well as the [object lifecycle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) in C++

Comment: @Keti_Kh you have to both "use `new`" and "avoid memory allocation inside the loop"? Get a new instructor, you aren't being taught C++

Comment: @Caleth I think the instructor means that they should rather allocate the variable once, before the loop, rather than allocating it in every iteration

Comment: @gkhaos and if they do they shouldn't be teaching C++. There should be zero occurrences of `new` in this program

Comment: @caleth haha yeah I'm slowly getting the same idea. thanks

Comment: @gkhaos yeah maybe

Comment: @Caleth On the one side, I agree with you, raw pointers is an outdated concept, we know better, on the other side, it is about knowing the enemy

Answer (score 0):

Move the deleting to outside of the loop:

```
double* n1=new double(0);

do
{
    cin >> *n1;

    //~stuff

}while /* ... */;

delete n1;
```

If you allocate inside the loop, you should delete at the end of the loop.

If you allocate before the loop, you should delete after the loop.

Comment: I haven't thought about that. I was thinking maybe I'd need to clear up the memory inside the loop so that i'd not use up unnecessary space

Comment: "Reduce, Reuse, Recycle".  Inside the loop you are reusing the allocated memory.  At the end, you are recycling the memory.  To Reduce, you should not be allocating memory in the first place; just declare the variable.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.